# How do I fix this error 'list out of range' in python?

Tags: python, list

I am writing this code where I need a number as a result. Check out the code below:

```
def prev_hosting_comp_random():
        with open('hostnumbers.txt') as hosts:
                read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n')
                read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts)]
                print(read_hosts)
                print(random.choice(read_hosts))

prev_hosting_comp_random()
```

the hostnumbers.txt file is like this:

```
1212
323
1314
45245
24
325
```

I am getting this error while running the code:

```
[root@b00gi3m4n boogieman]# python codeOffshoreupdated.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 23, in <module>
    prev_hosting_comp_random()
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 19, in prev_hosting_comp_random
    read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts)][0]
  File "codeOffshoreupdated.py", line 19, in <listcomp>
    read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts)][0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can you please help me fix this? Thanks

Comment: Your code worked for me.

Comment: For one of your rows, there was no column zero - likely you have an empty line in the file.

Comment: As @tdelaney mentioned you may have an empty line in your file.  I only get your error by inserting an empty line between other numbers.  I can work with empty lines by using `read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in read_hosts if x]` (note: `lists(...)` not needed for loop since read_hosts is iterable).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use `csv` for this. Just read the lines of the file with `readlines()`, it will create a list of strings using the newline character to separate them.

```
def prev_hosting_comp_random():
    file = open('hostnumbers.txt')
    lines = file.readlines()
    read_hosts = [int(x.strip()) for x in list(lines)]
    print(read_hosts)
    print(random.choice(read_hosts))
    file.close()

prev_hosting_comp_random()
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your answer. i need CSV as this is just a part of my code. This was working just fine yesterday and I think I might have missed something. Can you please tell me how do I fix my own code? I'll see if i can update your code as well

Comment: If you must use `csv` have a look at @Patrick Artner's answer where his list comprehension excules empty lines. This seems to be the likely issue with your current code

Answer (score 1):

Most proabably your file looks like this:

```
1212
323
1314
45245
24
325
   # here is an empty line
```

and your code crashes on that empty line when trying to access

```
 read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts)]   # x[0] on empty line crashes
```

---

You can fix your code:

```
def prev_hosting_comp_random():
    with open('hostnumbers.txt') as hosts:
       read_hosts = csv.reader(hosts, delimiter = '\n')
       read_hosts = [int(x[0]) for x in list(read_hosts) if x] # empty line == False
       print(read_hosts)
       print(random.choice(read_hosts))

prev_hosting_comp_random()
```

or even better read your file w/o using csv:

```
with open('hostnumbers.txt',"w") as f:
    f.write("""    1212
    323
    1314
    45245
    24
    325
""")

import random
def prev_hosting_comp_random():
    with open('hostnumbers.txt') as hosts:
        read_hosts = list(map(int, (h.strip() for h in hosts if h.strip())))
        return random.choice(read_hosts)

print(prev_hosting_comp_random())
```

As a sidenote, reading the file in multiple times is waste of time if you need to do this repeatedly - better to read / convert the file into a list of numbers once, and then pull one number from this list.